# Can a PC player join a PS2 server hosted on a pc in LAN?

Tags: pc, hosting, ps2, star-wars-battlefront-2

I am investigating the compatibility between the console version and the pc version of the game, with no results: I cannot find any information about joining a swbf2 server with both client versions.

This [thread here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/213989/how-do-i-play-multiplayer-on-star-wars-battlefront-2) explains how to get multiplayer now that the master servers are dead, but nobody mentions client compatibility.

If the vanilla server doesn't allow that is there any modded one that allows both PC &PS2 players?

So far my research has yield no result as I 'm unable to get the dedicated PS2 server (that's a PC program) to show up in the PS2 game list. The PS2 is emulated with pcsx2 (network configuration is good). Both PS2 and server are on the same PC. I will try the other way by using the PC version of the game to enter the PS2 dedicated server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This capability is completely possible! Just not available unfortunately.

If one could make a server hosting program that performs the baseline task of hosting the game itself, and translates the net code of each version, and disperses the unique net code to each console type (ie PS2 DNAS or PC version net code), then this would work! 
This is exactly what square enix did with FFX, so that everyone could play across all the platforms.

But, this does not currently exist. And would take a very long time to create.

Best present option is to run PS2X on the PC, and have a Local LAN party, or use a VPN setup like XLinkKai (which is specifically designed to play LAN capable PS2 games over the internet). Also allowing for an even playing field ;P.

Comment: Did you mean FFX? Maybe XI or XIV?