# Star Wars Battlefront II - Can I Do Multiplayer Within my Home?

Tags: pc, star-wars-battlefront-2

My friends and I are looking into buying Star Wars Battlefront II and playing it together. The original plan was to do this via Xbox when we all get together (let me know if this isn't possible), but I've discovered that the PC version is on sale on steam for $2.50. I'm wondering what the limitations are on multiplayer.

After doing some research, I've found that true multiplayer is a bit of a problem. There are third party programs you can use, but I'd rather not go that route. My question is: **if we are all in the same house and on the same wireless internet, can we do multiplayer?**

A side-question: can we play against each other *and* on the same side, or only one?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: The PC version is garbage.  It is missing maps and features of the main game.  I had it and always wished it was a full port of the PS2 version that I also had.

Comment: Because you mentioned that "true multiplayer" - probably meaning online multiplayer - would be a problem: To some extend, it isn't. Besides third-party applications like GameRanger and Tunngle there is a community-made project, SWBFSpy, that re-enables online multiplayer. There just aren't that many people online at a given time, but it can't hurt to check it out. More information: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/213989/how-do-i-play-multiplayer-on-star-wars-battlefront-2/230700#230700

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean multiplayer with multiple computers and copies of the game, yes.

One player can host a LAN game to just play on the same network. Ohter players can choose to join the LAN game. When hosting, the host should go to Settings>Host>Teams and put it on **Player Select** instead of the default, Auto-balance. With **Player Select** each player can choose which team they want to be on, allowing all humans to be on a single team, or divide themselves however they wish.

Comment: Yes, I am talking about multiplayer with multiple computers and game copies. Can we fight both against and with each other? Or just one?

Comment: Yes you can, I'll expand my answer.